# Assigning same action to multiple buttons at once

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

can I assign same action to multiple buttons in the Interface Builder once they are all selected by one connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is discussed in numerous threads but it isn't always just laid out simply.  The easiest route is to create a function such as the one below.  It takes the sender, in this case a UIButton, and gets the tag.  You can then run whatever code you want based on that.

```
- (IBAction) buttonClick: (id) sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Button clicked: %i", row);
    if (row == 1 ) {
    // do something
    }
}
```

In Interface Builder, attach the button to the function, and then use the Attributes Inspector to set the Tag value for each button, giving each one a different integer value.